# How do you use multple files in a JavaScript project that will not be used as a web application? Need a single working example

Tags: javascript

I'm kind of going nuts here.

I need to start writing a stand alone non web application in JavaScript.

My problem is that I can run (using nodejs) the script just fine, but I can't split the code that I need to write among multiple files because then I don't know how to include them.

Rigth now all I want is the simplest working example of including a JS file inside another so I can use the functions defined there (or class if I so choose).

My test.js looks like this.

```
const { outputText } = require("./text_module.node.js");
outputText();
```

While my text_module.node.js looks like this:

```
function outputText(){
   console.log("hello world");
}
```

My package.json looks like this:

```
{
  "type": "text_module.node.js"
}
```

I have tried

1. Adding export before the function. It tells me export is unexpected
2. Using this notation: `import { something } from "a_path"`. Anything that uses this notation will get me an "Unexpected token {" error.

The current configuration simply tells me that outputText() is not a function. So I'm out of ideas.

I don't know how else to search. I've been searching for hours on this topic and it seem that no matter where I look there is some HTML code that is needed to tie everything togeter or using another third party tool. Using jQuery loads stuff "asynchronically" which is not what I need. I want it to sequential.

Is JS just NOT suppossed to be used like other scripting languages? Otherwise I can't figure out why this is so complicated. I feel like I'm missing something big here.

Comment: You are importing a function that isn't exported by its module. You need to export the `outputText` function: `module.exports = { outputText };`

Comment: A quick google search for "Node JS modules" would have saved you some trouble.

Comment: I didn't know they were called this. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `const { outputText } = require("./text_module.node.js");`,

export it as `module.exports = { outputText: outputText }`.

In your question,

> Adding export before the function. It tells me export is unexpected

Because it's an es6 thing and nodejs doesn't support all es6 features. You can refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61131339/2427065) for more details on that.